# Getting Max Value Generic List For Each Item

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if you could help.

I have a list of information;

ClientNo
SequenceNo

This could contain data such as;

Cli No: 0000001, seq: 1 
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 2 
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 1 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 1 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2

I want to generate a list of the max sequence numbers.

Please note that the sequence number MAY be repeated numerous times, as per the example above.

So the list I would like to end up with from example about would be;

Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2

I have tried;

```
  var x = criticalNotesData.OrderBy(y => y.ClientNo)
         .ThenBy(z => z.SequenceNo).ToList();
  var m = x.Max(r => r.SequenceNo).ToList();
```

But the max is just providing the max sequence no in the list, rather than per client.

Thanks,

David

Comment: What's the deal with the duplicate client numbers? What's the logic behind your desired output?

Comment: why you need duplicate entries?

Comment: Each line of the sequence also has a field called "line no" and another called "text" attached to it. so i need the highest sequence no, and then combine all of the lines of text attached to that sequence, but I can do that part, just need to get the highest sequence per client no.

Comment: Are entries guaranteed to be already sorted by CliNo and then SeqNo? That can make a big difference in the way you process them, especially if data come from an 'expensive' resource. Linq operations which do buffering might impact on performance, and also on memory if items are a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `GroupBy` *twice* then `OrderByDescending` to get `First` instead of using `Max`, with this way, you don't need to *create new object* and still *get the duplicate max items*

```
var result = criticalNotesData.GroupBy(x => x.ClientNo)
                              .SelectMany(g => g.GroupBy(y => y.SequenceNo)
                                                .OrderByDescending(gg => gg.Key)
                                                .First()
                                           );
```

The result will be exactly what you want:

```
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000001, seq: 3 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2 
Cli No: 0000002, seq: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you need GroupBy

```
var maxItems = criticalNotesData.GroupBy(p => p.ClientNo)
                                .Select(r => r.Max(q => q.SeqNo));
```

something like this.
or

```
var maxItemsClientWise = from p in criticalNotesData
                           group p by p.ClientNo into r
                           select new { MaxSeq = r.Max(g => g.SeqNo), 
                                        Client = r.First().ClientNo };
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't try but I think this should work!

```
var m = x.GroupBy(r => r.ClientNo).Select(g => g.Max(x => x.SequenceNo));
```

EDIT: to know the client:

```
var m = x.GroupBy(r => r.ClientNo).Select(g => new { ClientID = g.Key, Max = g.Max(x => x.SequenceNo) });
```

Comment: You have no idea when enumerating `m` which client it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to get a list of your class object based on your criteria.

```
var query = (from t in list
            group t by t.CliNo into tgroup
            select new ClientSequence
            {
                CliNo = tgroup.Key,
                seq = tgroup.Max(r => r.seq)

            }).ToList();
```

It is assuming that your class structure is:

```
class ClientSequence
{
    public string CliNo { get; set; }
    public int seq { get; set; }
}
```

and your list is:

```
List<ClientSequence> list = new List<ClientSequence>
       {
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000001", seq= 1},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000001", seq= 2},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000001", seq= 3},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000002", seq= 1},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000002", seq= 1},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000002", seq= 1},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000002", seq= 2},
           new ClientSequence{ CliNo= "0000002", seq= 2},
   };
```

Output:

```
foreach (ClientSequence cs in query)
{
    Console.Write("Client No.: " + cs.CliNo);
    Console.WriteLine(" Max Sequence No.: " + cs.seq);
}
```

It will print

```
Client No.: 0000001 Max Sequence No.: 3
Client No.: 0000002 Max Sequence No.: 2
```

Comment: hello, thanks, what if my class structure was 
public class KNOWTXTS : ExcelReport
{
  public String ClientNo { get; set; }
  public String TextType { get; set; }
  public String SequenceNo { get; set; }
  public String LineNo { get; set; }
  public String Text { get; set; }
}
And i needed to also add the other fields to the query?

Comment: @DavidJohnson, only if you are returning a list of your class object, otherwise you can return any anonymous object and work with it

Comment: Sorry- I have another field in this class that I need to export on the new list, but I cant work out how to get it? when I add "LineNo" = g. I dont get a list of all of the fields in my list?

Comment: @DavidJohnson, sorry for my earlier comments,  you can't do that, and how do you expect that field to attach to any particular row ? if you want to group based on multiple columns you may see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541030/multiple-group-by-and-sum-linq

Answer (score 0):

You want, for each of the 'Client' entries, to know the highest sequence.  Thus that means the result should be a sequence (per client) rather than a single value as returned by Max.  How about:

```
var maxSequence = criticalNotesData
      .GroupBy(n => n.ClientNo)
      .Select(g => new { Client = g.Key, Max = g.Max(i => i.SequenceNo) } );

foreach ( var entry in maxSequence )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client {0} has max sequence of {1}", 
                      entry.Client, entry.Max); 
}

// Looking at your original, you now want only to know the (from the original)
// the entries matching MAX.  Since you now know the max per client, a second
// operation is needed.
var maxValueEntries = criticalNotesData
        .Where(n => maxSequence
                      .Single(c => c.Client == n.Client)
                      .Max == n.SequenceNo));
```

The `maxValueEntries` is doing a lot of lookups, so a Dictionary of values may be better.

```
// Turning the original into a Dictionary of clientNo returning the 
// max sequence.
var maxSequence2 = criticalNotesData
      .GroupBy(n => n.ClientNo)
      .Select(g => new { Client = g.Key, Max = g.Max(i => i.SequenceNo) } )
      .ToDictionary(c => c.Client, c => c.Max);
var maxValueEntries2 = criticalNotesData
        .Where(n => maxSequence2[n.Client] == n.SequenceNo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data like this:

```
var list = new []
{
    new { CliNo= "0000001", SeqNo= 1 },
    new { CliNo= "0000001", SeqNo= 2 },
    new { CliNo= "0000002", SeqNo= 1 },     
    new { CliNo= "0000001", SeqNo= 3 },
    new { CliNo= "0000001", SeqNo= 3 },
    new { CliNo= "0000002", SeqNo= 1 },
    new { CliNo= "0000002", SeqNo= 1 },
    new { CliNo= "0000002", SeqNo= 2 },
    new { CliNo= "0000002", SeqNo= 2 },
};
```

you can use this:

```
var output = 
    from i in list
    orderby i.CliNo, i.SeqNo
    group i by i.CliNo into g
    let max = g.Max(x => x.SeqNo)
    from r in g where r.SeqNo == max
    select r;
```

Is still valid what I said in a comment, the initial order of the data is important, in this code I took a general approach, but if you have guarantees about the initial order there are other strategies which can be more efficient if your source of data is expensive.